# What is causing this distortion?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

What is causing this strange behaviour in my map? As closer to the poles, the labels are distorted.

- Local OpenStreetMap data in PostgreSQL
- Geoserver
- OpenLayers
- Projection of data: 4326
- Projection of map (OpenLayers): 4326

I don't know what more I can tell. Please ask me for more information.

[image]

**Edit to add OpenLayers code asked by @Iant**

```
        landLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: MCLM.Map.geoserverUrl,
                isBaseLayer : true,
                projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'),
                params: {
                    'LAYERS': MCLM.Map.baseLayerName, 
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png8',
                    'tiled': true,
                    'antialias' : 'full',
                    'VERSION': '1.3.0', 

                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator is EPSG,900913 see insert statement http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator#PostGIS_.2F_SQL

Comment: Are you reprojecting prerendered tiles? They will always look bad

Comment: How are you requesting the data?

Comment: Thru Geoserver: `PostgreSQL -> PostGISStorage -> Layer -> Style -> WMS Service` and then `OpenLayers`

Comment: As @Mapperz says, the display is using EPSG:3857 AKA Esri:102100 AKA "Web Mercator".

Comment: Please add your code, so we can see where the reprojection occurs

Comment: @iant Done! see the edit. The OSM data (the `way` geometry column) is EPSG:4326 too. And the Geoserver layer configuration is EPSG:4326.

Comment: @mkennedy how can you conclude this?

Comment: The shape and size of the countries. When 4326 (lat-lon) data is displayed as if it is planar, Greenland has a squashed look. In 3857 which stretches north-south, it looks longer north-south. I work at esri on map projections.

Comment: @mkennedy good point. Can you see my own answer and check if all is fine? I can't see when I do the 3857 projection... all is in 4326 (from data to openlayers, passing thru geoserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont declare the projection of your map. To do so you need to place it in the view options. `projection:'EPSG:4326'` if you dont do it, your map will be projected in the default ol3 projection `EPSG:3857`. Doing so, will require to remove the ol.proj.transform, as there will be no need to transform the center.

Answer (score 1):

After thnking about the @mkennedy and @Mapperz comments, I investigate a little more and found the `View` code as this:

```
MCLM.Map.theView = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform( MCLM.Map.arrayMapCenter, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: MCLM.Map.mapZoom,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19             
});
```

There is a transform I don't know if is messing the map:

```
MCLM.Map.map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ landLayer ],
    target: container,
    renderer: 'canvas',
    ...

    view: MCLM.Map.theView
});
```

So even the layer is in EPSG:4326 the view is (I think) doing something wrong...

Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You dont declare the projection of your map. To do so you need to place it in the `view` options. `projection:'EPSG:4326'` if you dont do it, your map will be projected in the default ol3 projection `EPSG:3857`. Doing so, will require to remove the ol.proj.transform, as there will be no need to transform  the center

Comment: BINGO! What if you put it as an answer? Copy my View code, change the center: `center: MCLM.Map.arrayMapCenter` and add the projection attribute: `projection: 'EPSG:4326'`. I'll accept yours.

Comment: No worries, no need for amenities mate. Glad you found your way out

Comment: @pavlos You should make an answer anyway, so the question can be marked as resolved and future questioners will have an easier time finding the answer :)

Comment: Ok done. Hope it will help other people facing the same issue